# How to hide fields in ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

Basically i am struggling to hide some fields depending on the value of above dropdown selected in a form.

ex: say if i have a category dropdown than for a value of specific category show only specific fields before form submit.

Additionally also i want my categories to come using radio alert but its not showing ??

I tried to make category input a radio type select popup but unable to explore how to do that...

can any one suggest whats the best way.

I am thinking to do with https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/alert/AlertController/ .. example of radio alert.

Comment: you can place some code

Answer (score 1):

Your radio buttons are probably inside a [RadioGroup](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/radio/RadioGroup/) which has been bound with `[(ngModel)]="value"` or something like that.

This way you can hide/show certain fields (I'll demonstrate this with `div`s for now) by comparing them to a value.

```
<div id="onlyOnValue1" *ngIf="value == 'value1'"></div>
<div id="onlyOnValue2" *ngIf="value == 'value2'"></div>
<div id="value3Or4" *ngIf="value == 'value3' || value='value4'"></div>
```

This will look quite messy if you have a lot of fields to be hidden. So you can extract this into a function if you'd like.

You can also bind to `[hidden]` but I myself prefer using Angular's methods  instead.